# Why cannot convert java.util.stream.IntStream to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>

Tags: java, java-stream

Why cannot `convert java.util.stream.IntStream to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>`

```
    Stream<String> streamOfStrings = Stream.of("hello", "world");
    streamOfStrings.flatMap(String::chars).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This code gives a compilation error

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.stream.IntStream to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-) instead of `flatMap`:

```
streamOfStrings.flatMapToInt(String::chars).forEach(v -> System.out.println((char)v));
```